# How to get a particular document with the given ID exist or not in elasticsearch using groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am using a groovy script to append data to an array as follows

```
body = {
        "script": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "file": "demo_script",
            "params": {
                "users": array_ids
                }
            }
        }
es.update(index="demo_index", doc_type = "demo_type", id = uid, body = body)
```

My script is as follows,

```
if (!ctx._source.user_ids.contains(users)){ctx._source.user_ids += users}
```

In the groovy script, before I am appending the array elements (Here array_ids is the list of ids to be appended), I need to check whether a document exists in the ES with the given ID, In my case uid.
How can I do that in groovy scripting

Comment: Are you sure about the python tag for this question?

Comment: @fountainhead Yes, you are right. python tag is not mandatory here.